# Use NumericUpDown to select days in month

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker, numericupdown

Windows form application with a `NumericUpDown` and a `DateTimePicker`.
Using the `DateTimePicker` to allow the user to select a time (21.20)
I want to use the `numericUpDown` to allow the user to select a day.

How do I set the `numericUpDown` to only allow the user to select a valid day based on the number of days in the current month?

Comment: This is a very broad question with little to go on in the way of information.  I suspect the answer is easy to come by if you include code that you've tried already.

Comment: you can do this starting with a basic google search or look at some previous examples that have been posted out there on the web http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180523-numericupdown-increment-datetimepicker-day-increment/

Comment: @paqogomez I have searched around but all i can find are DateTimePicker issues, i cant find any for trying to use the numericUd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DateTime.DaysInMonth()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to set the Maximum() Property of your NumericUpDown() in the Load() Event of the Form:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown1.Maximum = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a mill, i feel kinda silly now,i was in the datetime picker trying to get the number of days and set the numeric max and mins from there, its all new to me. Thanks again